# Using an identical call, most, but not all, API Testers (ie Postman) throw an INVALID_SESSION_ID error

Tags: rest-api, api

I've used Postman to test callouts for a while. Recently, it has stopped working with at least one org. I can generate a session Id just fine, but every call fails with it. For example, Im testing with the below query:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://BASE_URL_HERE.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v56.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+Account' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ACTIVE_TOKEN_HERE'
```

Both Postman and Testfully return a 401 with an INVALID_SESSION_ID error. However, online testers like Site24x7 seem to "work" (it auto-encodes the URL resulting in a malformed query error but clearly gets past auth).

I have triple checked and copied and pasted to make sure all parts of the call are identical in all testers. Does anyone know what the cause might be?

EDIT: I am sure the access token did not expire. The call failed both before and after a success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same thing happen.  I think Salesforce recently changed something, I believe with the "My Domain" signatures.

###### tl;dr

Make sure your non-auth requests point to the URL that you see in the `instance_url` property found in the response to your auth request.

[image: Screen grab of properties returned in the body of the Salesforce auth request response]

*^ Properties returned in the body of the Salesforce auth request response*

---

###### The Way I (Hopefully) Futureproofed It

- I have an Environment Variable called `instance_url`.
- I have all of my non-Auth requests saved to use `{{instance_url}}`.
- In my collections I have an Auth request.  In the **Tests** tab of that request, I have the following (along with other lines not shown):

  ```javascript
  var jsonData = pm.response.json();
  pm.environment.set("instance_url", jsonData.instance_url);
  ```

Comment: Thank you! That did it